# How to define function Gradient of many variables?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to define a function with a list as input variables and obtain gradient of this function. I have tried many different ways, the simplest one which works is as following example,

```
xlist = {x1, x2};
f[{x1_, x2_}] := Module[{x, i, n},
   x = {x1, x2}; n = Length[x];
   Return[Sum[x[[i]], {i, n}]];
   ];
g[{x1_, x2_}] = Grad[f @@ {xlist}, xlist];
x0 = Table[2, {i, 2}];
f[x0]
g[x0]
```

This approach is OK for few variables, but it becomes inconvenient if I have thousands of variables.
Is there a simpler way?

In order to make Mathematica evaluate gradient (derivatives of each variable), I have to put all members of variables in the argument list as {x1_,x2_,...,x10000_}. This becomes a problem if I have several functions with long variable list. Is there a way to define this list once, and use it for multiple functions with a short notation?

The second issue is the statement x={x1,x2,...,x10000} which is needed in order to use x[[i]] instead of xi.
If possible, I would also like to define it once such as xlist ={x1,x2,...,x10000}; and use the short notation xlist many times in different functions like in function in my example. the notation xlist works in gradient function g, but does not work if I replace x={x1,x2}; with x=xlist; in function f.

Comment: One possibilty is to use Array... for example, Array[a, 5] creates five "variables" a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4] and a[5]. These could go in your xlist.

Comment: You mean `f[lst_] := Total@lst;
g[lst_] := Grad[f[lst], lst];
g@(x /@ Range[10])`?

Comment: xzczd's answer is close to what I need, for example, f[lst_]:=Module[{i}, Return[Sum[lst[[i]]^2,{i,Length[lst]}]];];g[lst_] := Grad[f[lst], lst]; g[{x[1],x[2]}] it returns {2x[1],2x[2]}. These are correct derivatives. But when I input g[{1,2}], I got error message as Grad::nocoord: "{1,2} is not a non-empty list of valid variables".  I hope it will return {2,4} instead.

Comment: `f[lst_] := Total[lst^2];
g[lst_] := Grad[f[lst], lst];
varlst = (x /@ Range[2]);
g@varlst /. Thread[varlst -> {1, 3}]` Be careful with evaluation order. Also, your question looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/284701), consider adding more details to the question.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want.